# Dynamically creating and executing sql commands in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, dynamic-sql

I am taking a database class and at the beginning of the lab section of the class we usually have to drop all the tables in the database created previously. I wanted to be able to run a script that does this dynamically, but cannot seem to get it to work. Here is the code I have so far.

```
declare tname string(50);
cursor ctable is select table_name from user_tables;

begin
 open ctable;
 LOOP
   FETCH ctable into tname;
   if tname != ''  then
     execute immediate 'drop table ' || tname;
   END if;
   EXIT WHEN ctable%NOTFOUND;
 END LOOP;
 close ctable;
end;
```

If someone could point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong that would great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle's `VARCHAR2` treats empty strings as `NULL`.
So

```
if tname != '' then
```

is the same as

```
if tname != NULL then
```

which will return `NULL` instead of `TRUE` since it is not defined.

You can check for `NULL` by `tname IS NOT NULL`.

`table_name` is mandatory in `user_tables` though, so there is no need for this check.

---

Two more things:

1. Check for `%NOTFOUND` immediately after fetching
2. Use column-references for variable declarations if possible ( `user_tables.table_name%TYPE`)

So your code could look like that:

```
DECLARE
  tname user_tables.table_name%TYPE;
  CURSOR ctable IS SELECT table_name FROM user_tables;
BEGIN
  OPEN ctable;
  LOOP
    FETCH ctable INTO tname;
    EXIT WHEN ctable%NOTFOUND;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table ' || tname;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE ctable;
END;
```

You could also use an implicit cursor for better readability:

```
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN ( SELECT table_name FROM user_tables ) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table ' || cur.table_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: You make look so easy. I debated whether or not to post this question because I knew it would be something simple. There are just no good resources online for pl-sql. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Looks like StackOverflow can be a good resource :)

Comment: If you are using foreign key constraints you will need to append ` cascade constraints` to the generated command, otherwise the DROP command will fail for referenced tables.